# Finding $\pi$ factorial

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, pi

This is the question I have: Find $ \pi! $

To find $\pi!$, I evaluated the gamma function at $\pi+1$ but ended up with a recursive equation as shown below.

$$ \int_{0}^\infty t^{\pi} e^{-t}  dt = \pi \int_{0}^\infty t^{\pi-1} e^{-t}  dt $$

I tried using integration by parts. I know that the answer is around $ 7.188 $ using online calculators but am unable to find the workings.

What is the method used to find $\pi!$ ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't analytically solve for $\Gamma(\pi+1)$

Comment: By applying the [Gauss Multiplication Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussMultiplicationFormula.html), one can derive the values of $\Gamma(x)$ whenever $x\in\mathbb Q$, though not much is known AFAIK about the closed forms whenever $x\notin\mathbb Q$.  A list of such values is given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) around $(70)$

Comment: If it is of any interest, this [pdf made by MSE user A. Walker](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf) provides closed form expressions (though not at all simple) of $\Gamma(a/b)$ whenever $b$ divides into $120$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the usual methods of approximating definite integrals? For example, [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule)? The online calculators are probably using something like that.

Comment: @MJD I just read up on Simpson's rule.  It's good enough for me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrals can be approximated numerically, without requiring a prior symbolic solution.  You only need to be able to evaluate the integrand.  This is typically how the online calculators produce their numerical approximations.

For example, [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) says that the value of an integral can be approximated by: $$\int_a^b f(x)\; dx \approx \frac{b-a}6 \left(f(a) + 4f\biggl(\frac{a+b}2\biggr)+f(b)\right)$$

with the error depending on how much $f(x)$  is like a parabola on the interval $[a,b]$.  By dividing the interval of interest into sub-intervals, approximating the value of the integral on each sub-interval, and summing the results, one can obtain good approximations even to functions that are not parabolas.