# Evaluating $\pi!$ with pi/gamma function

Tags: calculus, special-functions, factorial

Is it possible to evaluate $\pi!$ using the pi fuction without using any approximations? I'm trying to calculate it using the formula but I keep running through the problem that it gives a circular response:

$$x!=\Pi(x)=\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}dt$$
$$\pi!=\int_0^\infty t^\pi e^{-t}dt$$
$$\pi!={-t^\pi e^{-t}}\vert_0^\infty+\pi\int_0^\infty t^{\pi-1} e^{-t}dt$$
$$\pi!={-t^\pi e^{-t}}\vert_0^\infty+\pi\Pi(\pi-1)$$

But by defition, $x\Pi(x-1)=\Pi(x)=x!$, so:

$$\pi!={-t^\pi e^{-t}}\vert_0^\infty+\pi!$$
${-t^\pi e^{-t}}\vert_0^\infty$ converges to $0$, so:

$$\pi!=\pi!$$

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You can't get a closed form solution for $\pi!$, but if you want the numerical values it should be 7.188

Comment: So which numerical methods should a use to evaluate the pi fuction?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035071/finding-pi-factorial

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072821/what-is-pi-factorial

Comment: Disregard the factorial: is it possible to evaluate $\pi$ without using any approximation? We only know some trillion of digits of $\pi$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80).

Comment: $\pi !\approx \frac{\left(\frac{\pi }{e}\right)^{\pi } (1+12 \pi )}{6 \sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken when you assert that $\Pi(x)=x\Pi(x-1)$ by definition. This is actually a *property* of the $\Pi$ function. What you did was to prove that this holds when $x=\pi$.